# htaccess replacing underscores with hyphens

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a more efficient way to doing this?

The last /(.*)$ is an ID that I don't care to use. only whats before it.

```
RewriteRule ^about-us/news-room/(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?go=/news/press-releases/$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7-$8-$9-$10 [NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/news-room/(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?go=/news/press-releases/$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7-$8-$9 [NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/news-room/(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?go=/news/press-releases/$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7-$8 [NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/news-room/(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?go=/news/press-releases/$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7 [NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/news-room/(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?go=/news/press-releases/$1-$2-$3-$4-$5-$6 [NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/news-room/(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?go=/news/press-releases/$1-$2-$3-$4-$5 [NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/news-room/(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?go=/news/press-releases/$1-$2-$3-$4 [NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/news-room/(.*)_(.*)_(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?go=/news/press-releases/$1-$2-$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^about-us/news-room/(.*)_(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?go=/news/press-releases/$1-$2 [NC]
```

I found some solutions online but seem to get really confused on using the [N] flag?  Not too sure here.  Can anyone explain a better more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just let the rewrite engine loop internally for this:

```
RewriteRule ^about-us/news-room/(.+)/(.*)$ index.php?go=/news/press-releases/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^go=/news/press-releases/(.*)_(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?go=/news/press-releases/%1-%2 [L]
```

The first rule sends the request to index.php, and the second rule removes the underscores and replaces them with dashes. Because the rewrite engine loops, it'll keep applying the rule until either the recursion limit is reached or all the underscores are gone.

Comment: I was definitely wondering how it looped since all the other tries I did was crashing my web server. Now I see how the rules are based and the condition is set.  Thank you very good answer.